# MySQL making a poor optimization choice with ORDER by query and the EXPLAIN is incorrect

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem where mysql 5.6 is not using an index and causing very slow queries.

- Table named *people* with the following fields: *id, group_id, city_id*, ...
- Index that should be usable for group_id: *(group_id, city_id)*

The query is:

```
SELECT  people.* FROM people WHERE people.group_id = 12345 ORDER BY people.id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

The EXPLAIN for this query shows it not using the index and scanning 9324 rows:

```
possible_keys: index_people_on_group_id_and_city_id
key: PRIMARY
rows: 9324
extra: Using where
```

However, my slow query log shows the rows examined is huge:

```
Query_time: 16.254633  Lock_time: 0.000038 Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 7429457
```

1. Why does it not use the index?
2. Why is the optimizer so wrong? Do I need to somehow rebuild the metadata so that it realizes it has to scan more than 9324 rows and can then make a better choice?

I don't know where the number 9324 comes from. There is more than 10k records for group_id 12345.

edit: I discovered the size of the LIMIT is important here. With a LIMIT of 100 it uses the keys. With a limit of 10 it thinks incorrectly that it has to scan 9324 rows. With a limit of 1 it thinks incorrectly that it has to scan 932 rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even recreate this in any of my other environments. An explain of the same exact query on other databases shows it using the index.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your last edit as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered this is likely the result of a bug fixed in MySQL 5.7.6.

- Release Notes
  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-6.html)
- Bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73837

> For queries that combine ORDER BY with LIMIT, the optimizer may switch
>   to an index that applies to the ORDER BY. In some cases, the decision
>   to switch was based on a heuristic rather than on cost. The optimizer
>   now uniformly makes the decision whether to switch on a cost basis.
>   This should result in better performanance when switching would cause
>   a query to read an entire index or a large part of it to find
>   qualifying rows.

Comment: Your 5.6 will be end of life Feb, 2021. Time for an upgrade anyway.  You will likely find better performance.